# JavaScript override array method

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I've got a very large piece of JavaScript.

For some reason, under a specific circumstance, I'm getting an error:

```
"Object [object Array] has no method 'replace'"
```

Now I can't for the life of me find where it is, so I decided I'd actually create a special .replace() method for that type just so I can find out what is calling it to aid me in finding where to fix it. Question this method if you will, but the code is huge and it's going to save me time this way.

I can't figure out how to create that method though, and here is my attempt:

```
Array.prototype.replace = (function(a, b) {
    console.log('Oh boy Im being called by:');
    console.log(typeof(a) !== 'undefined' ? a : '');
    console.log(typeof(b) !== 'undefined' ? b : '');
    return;
})();
```

Comment: This likely means that the code *was given an array when it expected a string* instead. *Fix the code* (use the developer tools to isolate where the issue occurs) - don't try to "fix" it by this abuse.

Comment: I have several hundred instances of .replace. It's quicker to do this to find the issue, then I know where to fix the code.

Comment: The code will still be broken. It'll likely be more worthwhile to write unit tests and/or identify the specific source of the invalid array being introduced (which might "fix everything" by correcting input before it can permeate).

Comment: what you actually want to do, can you tell that, calling it like *[1,2].replace(1,2);* will do something.

Comment: There is _nothing_ wrong about using this trick to narrow down the cause of the issue.

Comment: $20 says there's a `.split()` running around somewhere...

Comment: I can't be sure, but it seems like document.location.href was returning an array. I'm not sure, either that, or the instance has just vanished. Alas, it's fixed.

Comment: *typeof* is an operator, not a function, there is no need to enclose the expression in brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want

```
Array.prototype.replace = function(a, b) {
   console.log('Oh boy Im being called by:');
   console.log(typeof(a) !== 'undefined' ? a : '');
   console.log(typeof(b) !== 'undefined' ? b : '');
   return;
};
```

The code as posted in the question executes the `replace` function immediately instead of anchoring it in the prototype.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, and I located the instances of replace that was the culprit.